# SocketException when trying to send data to mongoDB on Azure

Tags: mongodb, sockets, azure, mongodb-.net-driver, system.net.sockets

I have a mongodb replica set hosted in a VM wjth Windows Server 2012 R2 on the Azure platform, my problem is that when I'm trying to insert data from an external client using the C# driver or even consulting them from a GUI client (mongoVUE, robomongo ...) I often get the following exception which permanently locks the program (even trying a Server.reconnect() does not resolve).

```
No such host is known
Type: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Stack:    at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerAddress.ToIPEndPoint(AddressFamily addressFamily)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.GetIPEndPoint()
```

I've tried setting:

```
MongoDefaults.SocketTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
MongoDefaults.ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
MongoDefaults.MaxConnectionIdleTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
```

putting an hardcoded public IP address of the server in the connection string and testing it from different locations but it seems that something on the server blocking connections.

Has anyone any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Look around the net. I think you will find references to Azure instances "sleeping/parking/whatever" when they are not continually accessed. There will even be solutions. Google is your friend. That is not a product endorsement BTW :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved!The problem was that I started mongodb with a single replica set that's not configured correctly, removing the option --replset when starting mongod all works correctly.