# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known

Tags: c#, mongodb, sockets, networking, dns

I have two server machine. One windows machine on which .Net application running and
another Linux machine on which Mongo Db is configured.

.Net application on Windows machine  access database on Linux. 
But there is some random error on connecting to Mongo Database.
Error is random and goes after frequent retry.

```
 **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known
   at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress) 
   on connecting/login**
```

Is this issue related to database or there is some configuration issue with MongoDb

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this a couple of days ago...
What I would try:

1. Open the task manager and make sure there are no threads running in the background at the same port you have configured on your DB...
2. If you are using a virtual machine make sure your network state is set to bridge
3. If 1 & 2 doesn't work try to change the port on your database

**Hope it helps**

Comment: 1.No both machine are physical.                                                                                                            2.There are two database on second Linux Machine Postgres running on 5432 and MongoDb on Port 27017

Comment: Open the task manager and make sure there are no threads running in the background at the same port you have configured on your DB  --- Do you means on windows machine where my application is running

Comment: Yes. If you try to connect p.e to the Port 1111 where your DB is running but you have another thread connecting to another app at the same thread, you app, which is trying to connect to the database on your other machine wouldn't find the right port

Comment: can this be solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405130/socketexception-when-trying-to-send-data-to-mongodb-on-azure?answertab=active#tab-top